# How to connect two Java clients that are using STUN to get around NATs for a P2P connection?

Tags: java, networking, p2p, nat, stun

I've been working on a peer-to-peer file-sharing project in Java and have come to a wall that I don't begin to know how to break down. I have 2 clients running identical code, both behind NATs (probably, though assumedly not symmetrical NATs), who have accessed their public IP and port via a STUN server. When I attempt to make a connection between them, I get no response and the receiving client does not register an attempt to connect. This issue did not occur with the same code using local IP addresses.

Relevant connection code:

```
PeerConnection peerConn = new PeerConnection(pd);
            PeerMessage toSend = new PeerMessage(msgType, msgData);
            peerConn.sendData(toSend);
            
            if (waitReply) {
                PeerMessage oneReply = peerConn.receiveData();
                while (oneReply != null) {
                    msgReply.add(oneReply);
                    oneReply = peerConn.receiveData();
                }
            }
            
            peerConn.close();
```

```
public class PeerConnection {

    private final PeerInfo pd;
    private SocketInterface s;
    
    public PeerConnection(PeerInfo info) throws IOException {
        pd = info;
        s = NormalSocketFactory.makeSocket(pd.getHost(), pd.getPort());
    }
    public void sendData(PeerMessage msg){ s.write(msg.toBytes()); }
    public PeerMessage receiveData(){ return new PeerMessage(s); }
    public void close() {if (s != null){ s.close(); s = null; } }
```

Extraneous comments/try-catch and other code bits are omitted for brevity.

I am manually passing in the IP and port given by a STUN server (for testing purposes) into this peer connection, and other code is creating the actual data (connection type, who it's connecting to, etc) but I don't believe the content has any bearing on this as it can handle the input packets being created (as LAN tested has verified).

Am I missing something here? The clients are sitting there listening for a packet but aren't receiving them. Using WireShark (a program I am admittedly brand-new to) shows me that the connections are being reset (specifically that the `reset` flag is set, something that I in no way do).

```
.... .... .1.. = Reset: Set
    [Expert Info (Warning/Sequence): Connection reset (RST)]
        [Connection reset (RST)]
        [Severity level: Warning]
        [Group: Sequence]
```

I do not have a signaling server handling this as I do not have plans to host anything for the time being, but I don't much understand how I'd not come across a similar issue with that.

EDIT: After using WaifUPnP to allow ports to open through the firewalls, I still had issues with most connections I tried to test. I don't know if this is a symmetric NAT problem but a few connections have been made. I'm not gonna delete this in case someone else needs it later.

Comment: Which library are u using for p2p ? @Varian